# How to kill process under cygwin after using kill -9 which does not work

Tags: bash, cygwin

I am using cygwin on Windows7. 
I tried to kill process on cygwin using kill -9, but it said 'No such process'.

```
 $ ps
      PID    PPID    PGID     WINPID   TTY     UID    STIME COMMAND
     3976    6820    3976       5100  pty1    3042872 08:38:34 /usr/bin/ps
     2520    4404    2520       4016  pty0    3042872   Aug 20 /usr/bin/bash <defunct>
     5356       1    5356       5356  ?       3042872 23:46:31 /usr/bin/mintty
S    3724       1    3724       6656  pty0    3042872   Aug 21 /usr/bin/ssh
I    7080       1    7080       2108  pty1    3042872   Aug 21 /usr/bin/zsh
     6820    5356    6820       6156  pty1    3042872 23:46:31 /usr/bin/bash
     6988       1    6988        852  pty1    3042872   Aug 21 /cygdrive/c/Programs/emacs/emacs-24.3/bin/emacs
     4404       1    4404       4404  ?       3042872   Aug 20 /usr/bin/mintty
     5344       1    5344       5344  ?       3042872   Aug 21 /usr/bin/mintty
 $ kill -9 4404
-bash: kill: (4404) - No such process
 $ kill -9 6988
-bash: kill: (6988) - No such process
```

How can I kill those process. I tried kill that shell and start over again, that does not work.

Comment: do not `kill -9` http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8916/why-not-kill-9-a-process